# Searching for simple problems naturally solved using stacks

Tags: haskell, data-structures, stack, recursive-datastructures

I would like to know about simple problems that can be naturally solved using stacks with the usual interface (`emptyS`, `isEmptyS`, `push`, `pop`, `top`).

The complexity asociated to the context of the problem should be null. I can't touch topics like parsing, compiling or search algorithms at this moment. This discards many classical examples.

The most beautiful example I found so far is checking for balanced parenthesis in strings. In very few lines, without any other background, the exercise shows the utility of the data structure:

Another good example is procesing a string where the asterisk means to pop an item from the stack and a letter means to push it into the stack. The function must return the stack after the operations described in the string are applied to an empty stack.

If you can share some others problems, I will apreciate it very much.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Applications

Comment: @luqui I have edited the question. Would you please check it?

Comment: what would you like me to check?  Is something not working as intended?

Comment: @luqui You put my question on hold. I have edited it to follow the site guidelines. I would like it to be resumed.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem remains.  You have given some apparently working code, so there's no specific question about the code, and the question you have asked, which is the same question as before (examples of problems solved with stacks) is still too broad.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you asking for that is not covered in the wikipedia page and the answer given?  Do you just want more people's opinions?

Comment: No, I want more problems/exercises without baggage. I don't want to explain what are context free grammars, trees, search strategies, and so on in order to use stacks in some meaningful way.

Comment: @duplode, I tried to delete the question but SO didn't allowed me. I still belive that It is a valid question, so I have edited the question again to narrow the search, in order to lift the [close tag].

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is too broad, I am going to give some other applications. Some of other common applications are -

1. Parsing
2. Recursive Function
3. Calling Function
4. Expression Evaluation
5. Expression Conversion

   - Infix to Postfix
   - Infix to Prefix
   - Postfix to Infix
   - Prefix to Infix
6. Towers of Hanoi

Some details can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Applications).